# Parsing words separated with hyphen

Tags: regex

I require to parse the below string using regular expressions. I came up with two variants, both of which seem a bit ugly to me. Please assist me as to which would be better suited for the job.

The main task is to parse the url in scrapy.

**Sample expression** -

/article/2014/01/16/hcl-tech-earnings-shares-idINDEEA0F02920140116

**Regex** -

1. `/article/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/([0-9A-Za-z-]+)`
2. `/article/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/\w+(-\w+)*`

And yes, I need to capture the whole ending expression, so 1st regex has handled that perfectly. I verified both the regex using https://pythex.org/.

**Edit** -

Expected Format -

`/article/(yyyy)/(mm)/(dd)/(words-separated-by-hyphen)`

I want to capture all the stuff separated by `/` after `/article`

Comment: What is your Expected OP?

Comment: Could you show what you want to capture exactly with your example? The two regexes don't capture same things.

Comment: `/article/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(.*)`? If that satisfies the less ugly part...

Comment: @M42 Yes, they don't capture the same thing. The 2nd one doesn't capture the whole ending string.

Comment: I'd use @Jerry suggestion.

Comment: @Jerry Could you please convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
/article/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(.*)
```

The hyphens don't seem to have to do anything with what's in the url so...

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly well as desired. Thank you.